# Call directly without extra dialog in iOS using Ionic 4

Tags: ios, call, ionic4

I'm trying to call a number from my app, but I want to do that without having to click on the modal that appears with "Cancel" and "Call" after I clicked my button in the app. Just click the button in the app and go straight to the call. Can I do that?

I already installed the native plugin [call-number] and the ionic package. It's working, it's making the call, It's just that I would like to make the call without that extra step.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats possible. Plugins provide communication between the ionic layer and the native layer so you are usually limited by the options the plugin gives you.

According to the documentation all you can do is bypass the choice of the calling app.

https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass that dialog. It is provided by iOS as an extra layer of protection for the user. It stops malicious apps initiating calls that may incur costs without user acknowledgement.